# In MVC with Bootstrap External Popups, can you resize?

Tags: javascript, .net, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller, modal-dialog

If you load an external Modal dialog with bootstrap in MVC, its easy to set the height, for example:

```
$(".modal-body").height(300);
```

However, if I then send another view to that same popup (if they click a link within the popup which hits your controller and you return a different view to the existing popup window), then you may have a different size of content in this new view. So how can you resize the external modal dialog now?

My thought was to put JS code in that new view, and have an onload event:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".modal-body").height(530);
        alert("hit.");
    });
</script>
```

Well this code hits (the alert debug message 'hit' does show up), but the dialog height doesn't change from 300 to 530. So, perhaps the JS doesn't have access to that part of the DOM?

How can I get this second view within the same Modal dialog to have the correct height for its content?

thanks

Comment: The popup is in an Iframe, I should mention that. Turns out its the Iframe that is not auto-resizing the popup would be fine otherwise. I realize that changes everything, perhaps it will let me close this question

Answer (score 0):

So there was a Iframe inside of the popup and that was why the popups content size was not changed. There exists an issue where the popup content change isnt noticed anyway, but that is solved with the code I already had, posted above, but the below solves when its in an iframe if on the same domain as well.

The solution was on the site that the SRC in the iframe pointed to (the content of the popup) since hosted on the same domain, was to do:

```
parent.$(".modal-body").height(530);
parent.$("#myIframeId").height(500);
```